# convert a unicode string like "\udddd\udddd" to human readable string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Now I have a string like this "\u7c6e\u54c1\u23a8\u8357/\u4e01\u8f77\u7ba2\u7409" in Xcode, then I want convert it to "籮品⎨荗/丁轷箢琉" by Objective-C.

But I can't find any API to finish. 
What should I do? To get a string content instead of string literal.

Comment: Are you talking about a string literal or about the contents of a string? The Objective-C compiler will translate  "\u7c6e\u54c1\u23a8\u8357/\u4e01\u8f77\u7ba2\u7409" into a UTF-8 string and @"\u7c6e\u54c1\u23a8\u8357/\u4e01\u8f77\u7ba2\u7409" into an NSString*.

Comment: No. I know @"\u7c6e\u7c6e" is a unicode string, and I can't understand what's it actually. So I want to convert it to something normal I can read.

Comment: Sometime JSON string value responded from server prints in Xcode console like "\u7c6e\u54c1\u23a8\u8357". It's really inconvenient to debug.

Comment: @gnasher729 I write code like this,
            NSString *  unicodeCharArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\U05f3\U009e\U05f3\U00a2\U05f3\U2022"];
But it can't be passed by compiler.

Comment: @JerryRay `"\u7c6e\u7c6e"` is NOT an Unicode string. In fact, it's an ASCII string. This form of encoding is used by JSON in order to represent a string. The whole purpose of this encoding scheme is to represent an original Unicode string as ASCII.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes, you're right. I got it, that \u2334\u2342 is just a serial of escape characters, to transmit and represent a original string content. I was wrong, and have thought it's a problem about char-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is:

```
    NSString *tempStr1 = [unicodeStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\u" withString:@"\\U"];
    NSString *tempStr2 = [tempStr1 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
    NSString *tempStr3 = [[@"\"" stringByAppendingString:tempStr2] stringByAppendingString:@"\""];
    NSData *tempData = [tempStr3 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString* returnStr = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:tempData
                                                           mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                     format:NULL
                                                           errorDescription:NULL];
```

Comment: I think you are better of using a JSON library (e.g. NSJSONSerialization) and create a representation of the JSON, and then print that representation (which becomes a NSArray or NSDictionary), or alternatively, take the representation and convert it back to a JSON with the "pretty print" option which usually won't use escape encoding.

Answer (score 1):

My application does not need to convert, my situation is that: I have a response from server

```
name = "\U672a\U6765\U822a\U8def";
```

I just print log:

```
NSString *n = dict[@"name"];
NSLog(@"%@",n); //未来航路
```

I think your application is the same.

Comment: use NSLog block is not my intention. As debugger runs app slowly, it's too inconvenient to debug.